# time data '2015-08-19 11:11:51 %z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000'

Tags: python, django, datetime

I wish to convert one time zone(*GMT*) to another (*IST*) using python.
My datetime string `2015-08-19 11:11:51 +0000`

I am trying to convert datetime object 
`datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-08-19 11:11:51 %z",'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000')` 
But I am getting following **error**
`time data '2015-08-19 11:11:51 %z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000'`

`+0000` refers to time zone diff with respect to *GMT*.

Comment: Are you using python 2? %z is not supported in python 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `%z` is not supported by `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, you can try switching to Python 3.2.

Alternatively, you can use [`dateutil.parser.parse()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) which is 3rd party library:

```
$ pip install python-dateutil
```

--

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("2015-08-19 11:11:51 +0000")
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 19, 11, 11, 51, tzinfo=tzutc())
```